# Where's my GRUB2 menu gone?

Tags: dual-boot, grub2

I've installed 4 different 'Ubuntu' flavours on 1 laptop. For demonstration and comparison. (L, K, Mint & X)

I would like to clean up the GRUB menu, put a BG in etc., but I can't find it! There is, in each of the 4 installations/partitions a directory /etc/default/grub, but there's nowhere the 10 lines of choice to be seen.

Where is it? And if I can extract it from the MBR, where should I do that? In the first or the last partition ?
[image: My GRUB2 menu]

Comment: Fisrt you should see which of the flavours installed GRUB. Namely the last installed. To change configuration of menus (is that what you want?), you should start by editing the `/etc/grub.d/*` files. Lastly run `sudo update-grub`

Comment: I’d be inclined to install grub customiser if you want to do this. If you edit by hand an update could blow it all away.

Comment: How you installed the systems will dictate which controls the MBR (first 512 bytes of hdd/ssd). The last to write the MBR will own it, with the MBR pointing to it's /boot/grub/ and other systems /boot/grub/ will be ignored. We can't know what order you installed, or if you told any not to use MBR.  Mint is off-topic here, but you can make one own grub using `grub-install`

Comment: @Jan80TRS Is your drive partitioned as MBR or GPT? The response from guiverc directly above is right on, BTW.

Comment: The last one I installed is Xubuntu, and that appears at the top of the list. So, that's the last one to write to my MBR.
I checked with other dual/multi-boot systems I made before, and I realise that the actual menu cannot be edited from /etc/default/grub 
I was always told to stay away from the grub.d directory. I didn't know the grub Customiser existed. I'll check it out, maybe it's just what I want.
I installed each distro with an allocation of 60 GB, and let the rest take automation its course. They all work fine (Lubuntu has 1 err) Don't know GPT, I assume MBR was the way I did it.

Comment: I installed the Customizer on Xubuntu, the last one I installed. It works fine, I can change the lines and change for- and back-ground colors.
However, I also want to add a background pic and that doesn't work. I put in my user space (on the last partition) but in the grub config file, it points to 
GRUB_BACKGROUND="/home/main/Pictures/grub-bg.png"
Clearly, without partition information. Of course, I could put the file in the same place on the firts partition, but that seems to be a flaw in Customizer. And I can't find how to add partition information. Sorry, but I looked.